# In SharePoint, can I control what users see on the page programatically?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-wiki, moss2007-security, sharepoint-security

I have a SharePoint Wiki that I'm permitting anonymous users read-only access to.  However I'd like to make it so that the "Edit-History-Incoming Links" toolbar at the top vanishes if the user accesses the site so they don't get curious about that link, but a logged in editor is allowed access.  Is there any easy way to permit this?  Thanks!

Comment: Any sharepoint question with the "easy way" variable always results in the same answer: no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into wrapping whatever renders the links (perhaps on the masterpage) with a SPSecurityTrimmedControl using SharePoint Designer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx

Comment: To clarify a little, the best thing to do is to set visibility: hidden on the ms-wikieditouter stylesheet in the default.master page and wrap your securitytrimmedcontrol around that.  Thanks!